# eclipse doesn't find schemas

Tags: eclipse, xsd

When I compile my project in Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 10.4, I get this error message:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'.
```

The web-app element looks like this:

```
<web-app 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
```

As far as I know, the URLs are working, I can download the web-app_3_1.xdf file (from command line using wget through a proxy) but the compilation fails. Do you have any idea how to solve it? I've checked previous questions and answers, but I didn't see any option in Eclipse to turn off caching. Also the proxy is properly configured in Eclipse, at least I was able to download and install the GWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the trailing slash from the namespace in `xsi:schemaLocation`.

**Change**

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
```

**to**

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
```

so as to exactly match the `xmlns` attribute.

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately. Nevertheless, the very same code worked on Windows, so it is probably a problem in the environment (the Windows workstation has a more public IP address).